# want to merge two lines by removing beginning space from 2nd line

Tags: awk, sed, grep, vi

I have multiple lines in my file and want to merge 1st and 2nd line, and so on. Consider `________` as a space in 2nd line.

```
u_pcrd_logic/CTS_ccl_INV_clk_G1_L17_206                                         
________________________________2.001e+08       2.001e+08  0.0001773    0.001871   2.427e-07    0.002048     0.02934    INV_X6N_A9TL_C16

RC_CG_HIER_INST353/RC_CGIC_INST                                                 
______________________________2.001e+08       2.001e+08  0.0004888    0.001523    4.51e-07    0.002012     0.02882    PREICG_X6R_A9TL_C16
```

Expected output:

```
u_pcrd_logic/CTS_ccl_INV_clk_G1_L17_206     2.001e+08       2.001e+08  0.0001773    0.001871   2.427e-07    0.002048     0.02934    INV_X6N_A9TL_C16

RC_CG_HIER_INST353/RC_CGIC_INST     2.001e+08       2.001e+08  0.0004888    0.001523    4.51e-07    0.002012     0.02882    PREICG_X6R_A9TL_C16
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of [vi.se] for these kind of questions? Also, check [ask].

Comment: [edit] your question to correct the formatting using the editors `{}` button and replace all of the unnecessary space-replacement characters with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ sed '$!N;/ *\n  */s//     /;P;D' file
u pcrd logic/CTS ccl INV clk G1 L17 206     2.001e+08       2.001e+08  0.0001773    0.001871   2.427e-07    0.002048     0.02934    INV X6N A9TL C16

RC CG HIER INST353/RC CGIC INST     2.001e+08       2.001e+08  0.0004888    0.001523    4.51e-07    0.002012     0.02882    PREICG X6R A9TL C16
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following *spc.awk* script:

```
# spc.awk script

/^ / { #if the line starts with space
   lines=lines $0 # add the current line to the former recorded lines
   next 
}
{ # for every other line ...
   print lines # print the recorded lines 
   lines=$0 # record current line
}
END { print lines } # in the end print the last recorded lines
```

then use the command:

```
awk -f spc.awk your_input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '{$1=$1}1' file

u_pcrd_logic/CTS_ccl_INV_clk_G1_L17_206 2.001e+08 2.001e+08 0.0001773 0.001871 2.427e-07 0.002048 0.02934 INV_X6N_A9TL_C16

RC_CG_HIER_INST353/RC_CGIC_INST 2.001e+08 2.001e+08 0.0004888 0.001523 4.51e-07 0.002012 0.02882 PREICG_X6R_A9TL_C16
```

join the lines until one of more empty lines (record break), print with an extra empty line.